# Where can I find an administrative boundary shapefile for Monaco?

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, monaco

I am looking for an administrative boundary file (preferably in ESRI shapefile format) for the divisions of Monaco namely:

```
Condamine
Fontvieille
Jardin Exotique
La Rousse
Larvotto
Les Moneghetti
Monaco-Ville
Monte-Carlo
```

I have looked at a few websites like diva-gis, nationmaster, geofabrik, statsilk and eurostat but non of the files for Monaco are divided by the above areas, only the outline of Monaco itself. I need something akin to this image below...

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that image from? It might not be too hard to just digitise the boundaries from it - take care on that skinny bit along the harbour though...

Comment: Try a request at the [local statistics office](http://www.monacostatistics.mc/)

Comment: OpenStreetMap has some of those admin boundaries, but not a complete set, it seems...

Comment: Monaco with some subdivisions https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts filter by Monaco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

[image]

This is the source

Data Type:  ArcGIS Map Service

Connection: Internet

Server:     http://demographics2.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services

Name:       MCO_Demographics_and_Boundaries

Operations Allowed: Data (Find), Map (Display), Query (Identify)

Map Service Type: Not Cached

It can be added through add data button (from arcgis online). Just search for Monaco. It can be used as a REST service as well.

Comment: Hmm, broken link. Can you edit?

Comment: I only leave links on my website up for a few days after posting the answer. Space restrictions.

Comment: Do you know what the link is though?

Comment: added to answer